# why is graphicsDevice.viewport(x,y,z,w) using the x for x and the y?

Tags: c#, xna, camera

I am trying to create a splitScreen for my XNA game.  I have a camera class that i use as the cameras and when  it comes time to draw i call the function that contains the code below. the cameraViewport is a vector4 that all values are between 0,1.
for the first camera i use

```
camera1.viewport = new vector4(0,0,1,.5f); // this works perfect
```

and for the second camera i am using

```
camera2.viewport = new vector4(0,.5f,1,.5f); // this is drawling the same view as camera1
```

but when i do this for camera two

```
camera2.viewport = new vector3(.5f,0,.5f,.5f);
```

it turns out to be as if i was spliting it 4 ways and its in the botom right, but it should be in the top right.  so it looks like its not using the y value at all and just using the x value. why is that?

```
            int x = (int)(defaultViewport.Width * CameraViewport.X);
            int y = (int)(defaultViewport.Height * CameraViewport.Y);
            int w = (int)(defaultViewport.Width * CameraViewport.Z);
            int h = (int)(defaultViewport.Height * CameraViewport.W);
            Viewport viewport = new Viewport(x, y, w, h);
            graphics.Viewport = viewport;
            this.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), viewport.AspectRatio, .1f, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was my bad, the error was in how i was setting the viewport.

```
Vector4 cameraViewport;
public Vecor4 viewport
{
     Vector4 newviewport = value;
     cameraViewport = new Vector4(mathhelper.clamp(newviewport.x,0,1),...  //here was my problem i was setting the y value the same as the x value i didnt even think to check here sorry for this kinda point less question unless someone else has the same problem.  
}
```

Comment: says i have 2 days before i can thats why i havnt